# Щиросердно чи щиросердечно?

Tags: орфографія

На сайті "Словопедії" пишуть так: ЩИРОСЕРДНО - см. щиросердечно.
   Значення одинакове, це зрозуміло, але в інших випадках щиросердечно порівнюють з рос. "чистосердечно" і вживати не рекомендують. То яке слово обрати?

Comment: якщо вам не складно, додайте посилання на випадки, коли щиросердечно порівнюють з "чистосердечно".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мені теж зразу згадалося рос. "чистосердечно", а зовсім не питомі **прикметники** в класиків з відповіді вище. Якщо мова про прислівникову фразу в контексті "говорити правду", то, як на мене, по-нашому природно звучатиме *"по щирості"*, *"по-щирому"*. [В Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/32571-neobludno.html) ще є чудове слівце *"необлудно"*.

Гадаю, *"щиросердно"* є адекватним лише в контексті сердечних, так би мовити, справ:

> Коха́в він мене́ ві́рно, щиросе́рдно (Кон.).
>
> Я вас по [настоя]-щему люблю – я вас правди́во люблю́ (коха́ю), я вас по пра́вді (таки́ спра́вді, щи́ро, щиросе́рдно) люблю́ (коха́ю);

А якщо *"чистосердечно признаться"*, то це радше "зізнатися по щирості":

> Призна́юсь вам по щи́рості тепе́р (Грінч.)

Джерело:  [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Контекст рулить. :)

Answer (score 1):

Насправді є цілих три прислівника:

[ЩИРОСЕРДЕ́ЧНО](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE), [ЩИРОСЕ́РДНО](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE) і [ЩИРОСЕ́РДО](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE),

які відповідають трьом прикметникам:

[ЩИРОСЕРДЕ́ЧНИЙ](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), [ЩИРОСЕ́РДНИЙ](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), [ЩИРОСЕ́РДИЙ](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9).

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/) всі прислівники просто відсилають до статей про відповідні прикметники.

А прикметники "щиросердечний" і "щиросердний" відсилають до статті про прикметник "щиросердий".

З одного боку, могли б сказати, що основна форма - саме "щиросердий", але подивимось на джерела:

Слово ["щиросердечний"](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) використовує М. Коцюбинський:

> Признаюся, мені дуже приємні і Ваше співчуття до моїх замірів і
>   бажання помогти їм. Ще раз засилаю Вам за те щиросердечну подяку!

Слово ["щиросердний"](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) вживає якийсь невідомий автор, Семен Журахович.

Словом ["щиросердий"](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9) користується Нечуй-Левицький:

> Він працьовитий, щиросердий, і в його є тямка в голові; душа в його
>   добра.

Так само Коцюбинський вживає й прислівник [щиросердечно](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE), а Олесь Гончар користується прислівниками [щиросердно](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE) і [щиросердо](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE).

Вимальовується така картина:

Коцюбинський - це класик української літератури, до того ж, маємо послідовність у його вжитку прислівникової та прикметникової форм з цим коренем. Гончар використовує прислівники непослідовно. Нечуй-Левицькому я б також довірився з приводу мови, бо він дуже ретельно працював над своїм стилем.

Мій обережний висновок такий:

Хоч всі три слова і є словниковими, а отже вживати їх можна без вагань, та все ж таки *стилістично* краще обмежитися в більшості випадків двома варіантами: "щиросердечно" ("щиросердечний") та "щиросердо" ("щиросердий").